# Удаление блоков элементов

Tags: c++

Создать функцию, позволяющую удалять блок элементов произвольного размера, начиная с произвольного индекса массива.
Люди объясните пожалуйста как правильно удалить несколько элементов из динамического массива:)

Comment: Переместить оставшиеся  элементы в новый массив, а старый удалить (освободить память)

Comment: Переместить на их место остающиеся в массиве и отслеживать количество элементов в массиве - если всерьез, а если то, что хотят преподы - то, вероятно, выделение нового массива, перенос нужных элементов, освобождение старого?...

Comment: В принципе логично)
Спасибо)